# Не могу увеличить скорость запроса

Tags: mysql

Есть две таблицы: Клиенты, Заказы_Клиентов. Хочу сделать запрос, кто из клиентов делал последний заказ в этом году

```
SELECT clients.*, orders.date FROM clients LEFT JOIN orders USING(client_id) 
WHERE orders.date >= '2015-01-01' GROUP BY client_id ORDER BY orders.date DESC;
```

Индексы у таблиц есть. 
Всё бы ничего, но на 100К клиентах и на 1М заказах скорость выполнения запроса отставляет желать лучшего. Ничего лучше чем ввести клиенту колонку с датой последнего заказа я не нашёл, но может можно оптимизировать запрос?

Comment: `SELECT  * FROM  clients
WHERE client_id IN (SELECT client_id FROM orders WHERE date >= '2014-01-01' GROUP BY client_id);` выполняется намного быстрее, но не показывает дату последнего заказа.

Comment: Индексы пробовали добавить? Я бы попробовал добавить на orders.date, client_id.

Comment: Индексы и на client_id и на date есть

Comment: Автор не слушай их. Вот тебе на будущее
http://citforum.ru/database/digest/dig_2412.shtml
Поверь как человеку работающему с базой одной из крупнейших компаний РФ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT o.m_d, c.* FROM 
(SELECT client_id, MAX(date) AS m_d FROM orders WHERE date >= '2014-01-01' GROUP BY client_id) AS o
INNER JOIN clients AS c USING(client_id);
```

Вот так получилось очень быстро и то что нужно. Спасибо @IvanZakirov

Answer (score 1):

конструкция JOIN увеличивает время обработки запроса при большом количестве записей (ну там еще от условий зависит).

```
SELECT 
  clients.*, 
  max(orders.date) -- вывести максимальную дату, она же последняя (желательно еще там время учитвать, вдруг в 1 день несколько клиентов брали заказы)
FROM 
  clients c,
  orders o
WHERE 
  c.id = o.client_id
GROUP BY 
  client_id 
ORDER BY 
  orders.date DESC
```

или еще вариант по максимальному ID заказа - он же последний будет:

```
SELECT 
  clients.name, 
  max(orders.id) -- вывести максимальную дату, она же последняя (желательно еще там время учитвать, вдруг в 1 день несколько клиентов брали заказы)
FROM 
  clients c,
  orders o
WHERE 
  c.id = o.client_id
GROUP BY 
  clients.name 
ORDER BY 
  orders.date DESC
```

Comment: Да собственно и мой и ваш запрос дают приблизительно одно и тоже время 9 - 11 секунд. Это очень много

Comment: Попробуйте сначала обработать таблицу заказов. Вытащить максимальную дату.
SELECT client.name
FROM client c,
(SELECT max(orders.id), orders.client_id) o
WHERE
c.id = o.client_id

Comment: Первый вариант содержит лишние поля. См. [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)
Второй вариант группирует по client_name, а разве где-то сказано, что поле уникально идентифицирует клиента?

Comment: Не в том месте и не с тем мериться письками пробуете. Мне это не интересно. Я автору дал информацию и вы дали. Какую он посчитает верной путь ту и использует. А все ваше советы, какой-то бред(в прошлом чушь:)) и еще особенно выражение "....поле уникально идентифицирует клиента...". Уникально идентифицирующее поле это поле используемое первичным ключом, уникальное не имеющее повторений значение. Сами то хоть читаете ? и причем тут группировка и уникальное идентифицирующее поле ? А лучший вариант написан в комментарии. И писал лишь рекомендацию основываясь не первом посте вопроса. Зная базу...

Comment: ...зная базу запрос был бы вполне возможно другим и по другому построен. Еще раз повторюсь - я писал не решение готовое, а рекомендацию к подходу получения информации из базы. И не собираюсь с вами спорить более. Здесь две таблицы имеющий первичный ключ в одной и связь с другой по вторичному. Никакие составные индкесы, дистинкты и т.п. для простейшего запроса не нужны. И парень верно с ориентировался и написал как у него быстро стало работать при этом используя JOIN, хоть я и говорил не надо. Но я писал - рекомендацию к подходу.

Comment: @IvanZakirov, никто на вас не нападает, клянусь. Давайте обсуждать SQL запросы, а не кто что сказал или подумал.

Answer (score 1):

Безотносительно скорости, так писать нельзя:

```
SELECT * … GROUP BY client_id
```

По правилам SQL при группировке допустимо указывать во фразе SELECT поля из фразы GROUP BY + агрегатные функции от других полей. MySQL *при некоторых настройках* допускает вольности, но это (а) может сломаться при переносе на другой сервер и (б) дает негарантированный результат.

Данную задачу можно решить через подзапрос, как мне кажется, с хорошей производительностью:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM
  `clients` AS c INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT `client_id`
    FROM `orders`
    WHERE `date` >= '2015-01-01'
  ) AS co USING(`client_id`)
```

(Здесь вместо SELECT DISTINCT… в подзапросе можно применить … GROUP BY client_id, даст тот же результат.)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by

**Edited**: внимательно перечитал вопрос и понял, что надо добавить *дату* в подзапрос. С появлением агрегатной функции от GROUP BY уже не увернуться :)

```
SELECT co.`max_date`, c.*
FROM
  `clients` AS c INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT `client_id`, MAX(`date`) AS `max_date`
    FROM `orders`
    WHERE `date` >= '2015-01-01'
    GROUP BY `client_id`
  ) AS co USING(`client_id`)
```

Comment: Вот как ни странно, в другом запросе, где я поменял GROUP BY на DISTINCT скорость упала раза в 2 - 3. Не знаю с чем это связано, но я решил не рисковать

Comment: Дело хозяйское. Проверить *этот* случай, а не другой нетрудно, правда? Теперь у вас есть разные варианты, пробуйте, выбирайте, анализируйте через explain.

Comment: конечно скорость упадет. В случае с Group BY сервер по индексированным полям выбрал из миллионов записей нужные и вывел только их. Если заменить GROUP BY на DISTINCT - то в этом случае сервер будет выбирать все миллионы записей, а потом уже по выбранным будет идти и искать повторяющиеся по всем столбцам.. уловили сколько лишних итераций над данными ?

Comment: Не все то, чем кажется! Я вам больше скажу: *как* *правило*, group by приводит к полному перебору. Просто попробуйте, померяйте, посмотрите план запроса. Теория ничто без практики.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800432/mysql-select-distinct-efficiency-for-very-large-tables

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html

Comment: @artoodetoo
Все дело в том, что я как раз таки не теорию толкую, а практику.
Ваши статьи говорят об оптимизации той или иной функции в частности DISTINCT по существующей структуре из примеров статей. 
А я человеку советую как лучше написать по его сейчас существующей структуре. А делать составной индекс указанный в вашей таблице - это чушь. И в его случае заменять GROUP BY на DISTINCT - тоже чушь.

Comment: @IvanZakirov, вы злоупотребляете словом "чушь" ) И еще неверно трактуете чужие слова. Всё вместе тянет уже на троллинг. Я, например, не призывал буквально заменять group by на distinct. Я писал, что в *указанном* *контексте* они равнозначны. Про индексы вы вообще из другой ветки выдернули, я про них молчу.

Comment: Чтобы добиться хорошей производительности, надо стараться отсечь максимум ненужных данных как можно раньше. Я полагаю, что мой запрос *может* получить план, близкий к оптимальному. Но надо смотреть вживую. Реальный план выполнения конечно будет зависеть от индексов, их покрытия и от объемов данных.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в клиента ссылку на последний его заказ - увидите разницу. Реально облегчит работу сервера и уменьшит время ответа.

**Добавил:**

Решение (если запросы не удовлетворяют в данный момент с тем сервером, что есть): перенести в архивную таблицу старые "ненужные" (этому важному запросу) данные, всё время работать с оперативной табличкой (текущий год). Для всёх остальных потребителей данных (которым нужно всё) - сделать View (вид) и "спрятать" эти старые и оперативные данные - то есть сделать общий интерфейст, который будет скрывать физическую структуру баз данных, но не повлияет на фукциональность клиента (клиент будет общаться с видом, а вот тот, кто хочет получить текущие данные из маленькой таблички - получит их напрямую).

Comment: Так и сделано сейчас. Но не любитель я вводить дополнительные поля, если информацию можно извлечь и так.

Comment: @ArchDemon ну тогда нечего хранить заказы за все годы в одной табличке. )

Comment: @garik не говорите глупостей. База данных создана чтоб хранить информацию и никто ее не делит по табличкам если много записей. Нужно лишь подход верный делать. Создавать дополнительные поля ради той информации что и так можно вытащить - денормализация неоправданная. Нормальному серверу вытащить нужную строку из таблицы с миллионами записей делов на 0.005 сек.

Comment: @IvanZakirov никто не делит, вы уверены? здесь речь идет о больших табличках, а не презентационных красивых структурах баз данных о которых Вы наверно читали в книжках. Сразу вспоминаю анекдот про двух блох, одна другую спрашивает: интересно, если ли жизнь на других собаках. ) по Вашему ответу собеседование Вы пройдёте.

Comment: @garik по вашему столь уверенному опровержению моих слов у вас будет не лучшая база данных.
Я работаю в фирме одной их крупнейших в РФ и занимаюсь программированием и обработкой информации на базе данных Oracle. И знаю что такое информация и как ее хранить/обрабатывать не только по книжкам. А по двум образованиям и опыту работы, в том числе и ERP системы построенной полностью на базе данных.
Можете и дальше опровергать сколько угодно. Давать советы делить таблички если там много записей на несколько... задолбаетесь потом их собирать воедино, когда надо будет налоги или ЗП обрабатывать.

Comment: @IvanZakirov Требования читали? Человеку нужно быстро получить данные по большой табличке. Насколько понимаю нет у него фермы серверов и надо данные за один последний год (текущий, не предыдущий-е). Ваша крупнешая компания в опасности - Вы не читаете требования. Обновил свой ответ.

Comment: есть у него ферма или нет, а принцип вытаскивания запроса - всегда одинаков. Производительность конечно разная будет. Но делить на таблицы - не ускорит ничем сие действие, вы так же будете перебирать все таблицы, т.к не знаете в какой хранятся нужные данные. Или вы пишете все в блокнот ? ну удачи вам. Мне этот бесполезный спор как-то поднадоел..

Comment: @IvanZakirov крупнейшая фирма в опасности! ) недельные курсы по ораклу и можно даже не знать об partition views. а зачем, достаточно назвать сильное слово ERP!

Answer (score 1):

А поле `client_id` к какой таблице относится? Если это `clients.client_id`, то лучше использовать поле клиента из таблицы orders. Соответственно и индекс для полей `orders.client_id`, `orders.date` (скорее всего лучше составной) должен быть в таблице `orders`.

Важно, чтобы все операции по выборке проходили над одной таблицей.

```
SELECT clients.*, orders.date 
FROM clients LEFT JOIN orders USING(index_in_table_orders) 
WHERE orders.date >= '2015-01-01' 
GROUP BY orders.client_id 
ORDER BY orders.date DESC;
```

Comment: client_id есть в обеих таблицах. Иначе бы я не смог их объединить через `USING()`. Проблема не в том, что я указываю поле не из той таблицы (mysql с этим сам справляется), а в том что mysql сначала объединяет таблицы, только потом применяет фильтр. А это долго

Comment: если бы это поле было в обеих таблицах, была бы ошибка "column client_id is ambigous". Укажите в запросе явно, GROUP BY orders.client_id. Это нужно сделать как раз для того, чтобы mysql выполнил все операции выборки и группировки над таблицей orders, а потом уже сделал JOIN.

Comment: Предупреждения нет. При явном указании скорость работы не увеличивается.

Comment: @user1778019 тоже не порите чушь. Серверу плевать из какой таблицы вы вытащили данные в блок SELECT, если таблицы связаны верно между собой. Он что так что так подготовит данные из обеих таблиц. Только лишь отобразит те, что находятся в SELECT.
Опираясь на слова "с индексацией все впорядке", достаточно поочередно опередлить критерии выборки информации из таблиц, составить подзапросы и из миллионов строк будет вытаскиваться за секунды а то и меньше. Конечно если железо позволяет к тому же ;)

Comment: @user1778019 ах да, про составной индекс в вашем ответе - тоже полная чушь. Индекс по полю который и так проиндексирован да еще и составным с полем дата.... господь спаси от таких запросов всех кто ждет от них результаты и тех кто правит потом такие запросы.

Comment: IvanZakirov, причем здесь блок SELECT? Я говорю о том, что поля, по которым идет выборка, группировка и сортировка должны быть, скорее всего, проиндексированы и хорошо, если эти поля находятся в одной таблице.  Думаю, что у этих полей достаточно высокая селективность для этого, учитывая, что в таблице порядка 1М записей. Что плохого в индексе с полем дата? Лучше перебор?! А то, что индекс уже существует - можно его изменить.

Comment: Вообще неплохо бы увидеть EXPLAIN. А не полагаться на утверждение "с индексацией все впорядке".  ArchDemon, почему не  сделать ORDER BY по orders.id?